# svn vendor branch with out-of-order releases

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, vendor, vendor-branch

How do you deal with svn vendor branches when releases from the 3rd party vendor come out-of-order in their version number.  eg, consider releases in this order:

- 1.0.0
- 2.0.0 alpha
- 1.0.1 (minor point release)
- 2.0.1 beta
- 1.1.0 (new features added)
- 2.0.2 final

We merge to the trunk various versions from any of the above, depending on what stage the project is in.

What's the best way to handle this in svn for vendor branches?  Should each release be committed to \current?  Would the history be preserved properly?  Also, depending on the amount of changes, a lot of space would be wasted going back and forth between versions (we're talking about large software packages).

It's important to me to keep the merge history, so I'd like to keep using \current as recommended by the svn red book.  But the differences between versions might be so dramatic that it wouldn't make sense to keep every version on the same development line.

Comment: Why not just maintain 2 vendor branches, one for 1.x and the other for 2.x?